# Find a value for $c$ such that $f(x)$ is continuous. Am I correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Please see my work below. I want to make sure I did this problem correctly; Is there some way to check if the function is continuous when c = 5/2, so I know that I am right?

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right. Indeed c=5/2 is the only value for which the function is continuous.

Comment: Thanks- exactly what I needed.

Comment: As a check, you could show that $$\lim_{x \to 2^{-}} \frac{5}{2}x^2 - 3 = \lim_{x \to 2^{+}} \frac{5}{2}x + 2$$

Answer (score 0):

In order for the ordinary limit to exist as $x\to2$, the left-side and right-side limits must be equal. Remember that $x\to2^-\implies x\lt2$ and $x\to2^+\implies x\gt2$.
$$\lim\limits_{x\to2^-}(f(x))=\lim\limits_{x\to2^+}(f(x))\implies cx^2-3=cx+2$$
We can apply direct substitution.
$$c(2)^2-3=c(2)+2\implies c=\frac{5}{2}$$
We can verify our solution with the definition of continuity at $x=2$. Let us first determine the value of $f(2)$.
$$f(2)=\frac{5}{2}(2)^2-3=5(2)-3=7$$
Now, following user N. F. Taussig's suggestion in the comments, let us find the left-side and right-side limits as $x\to2$ again, but this time we won't be solving for $c$. Instead, we will be solving for the actual limits.
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to2^-}(f(x))&=\frac{5}{2}(2)^2-3=5(2)-3=7\\
\lim\limits_{x\to2^+}(f(x))&=\frac{5}{2}(2)+2=5+2=7
\end{align}
Everything is in order here; you solved the problem correctly.
$$\lim\limits_{x\to2}(f(x))=f(2)=7$$